# Exploding memory usage while building large dict of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, out-of-memory

I'm generating lots of nested list from a text tokenizing process and would like to store them in a dict with keys that relate to the key of the string in the source dict.

Example of source dict:

```
{
    '1' : 'the horse',
    '2' : 'grass is green',
    ...
}
```

Example of desired output, where the integers are outputs of tokenizing and hashing process:

```
{
    '1' : [[1342, 24352, 524354, 356345],
           [35663, 53635, 25245, 457577]],
    '2' : [[43412, 324423, 66546, 86887],
           [398908, 46523, 432432, 9854],
           [87667, 34423, 132132, 35454]],
    ...
}
```

As I iterate through my source dict, feed my tokenizing function the values and assign the key, tokenized value pair to a new dict, my new dict is using a massive amount of memory that's way larger than the actual space it should take up.

Here's some simulation code that illustrates my issue:

```
import gc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import json

import os
import psutil

pid = os.getpid()
py = psutil.Process(pid)

def memory_use():
    memoryUse = py.memory_info()[0]/2.**30  # memory use in GB
    return memoryUse

def tokenize_sim():
    # returns a list of 30 lists of 4 random ints
    # (simulates 30 tokenized words)
    return [[int(n) for n in np.random.randint(low=0, high=1e6, size=4)] for i in range(31)]

memory = []
tokens = dict()
for i in range(800001):
    tokens[i] = tokenize_sim()
    if i % 50000 == 0:
        memoryUse = memory_use()
        print(i, '- memory use:', memoryUse)
        memory.append(memoryUse)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(17)*50, memory)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Thousands of iterations')
plt.ylabel('Memory used in GB')
plt.show()

print('System size in bytes:', sys.getsizeof(tokens))
```

Here's the plot of memory usage:

[image: Linear growth of memory usage]

`sys.getsizeof(tokens)` returns 41943144 bytes. I tried writing this dict to a json file and that used 821 MB. None of these are even close to the 6 GB of memory this is gobbling up.

What am I missing here? I'm guessing it's some memory allocation issue, but I haven't managed to find any solution. I need to process a source dictionary of about 12 million entries and my 64 GB of memory just don't seem to be enough to build a dict of lists. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Objects have overhead. JSON being smaller than the deserialized form is normal.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really grasp what you're doing aside from plotting your memory usage (might want to scrap the code that isn't really related to the problem), but I can give you some general pointers how to handle lots of data and why it eats up all your memory.

The reasons. Python isn't really a high-performance language in terms of efficiency and speed. In Python, everything is an object and every object has their own properties. When you create a nested list of properties, then the parent list, all the nested lists and every little integer has their own stuff attached to them - their own metadata and description. You can visualize that when you call `dir()` on different objects - for example an integer in Python has 69 different methods and attributes attached to it. And all of those have to fit in the memory, this is why your memory is gobbled up much faster than the actual size of the JSON format which doesn't hold any metadata about the data.

How to combat that? There are languages out there that are much better with handling big amounts of data simply because they are not so developer friendly and look out for you every step of the way. You could switch to C and accomplish the task with 8 GB of RAM.
But I'm not recommending to switch languages, just use some better practices. Right now you're holding all your data in lists and dicts (?) which really isn't efficient. Look up what **numpy** and **pandas** can do for you  - they are exactly meant for such use cases. They are implemented in C which provides much better performance while having a Python API that makes usage rather convenient.

If that isn't enough, just do what you're doing in chunks. If all you want is a huge list of lists with some integers in it, you can do it in iterations while saving all of it in intervals and you don't need it all in the memory at the same time. If Python native garbage collection isn't enough, you can try to force Python to release memory by `del`ing the huge variables and calling garbage collection.

```
import gc
del big_bad_variable
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Your point still stands, but each object does not carry around a separate copy/reference to each of the methods it can access.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I admit my description of the inner mechanics isn't too accurate on that part, but it gives a rough idea what are some of the overhead reasons.